# Preserving local variables when calling function again

Tags: javascript

I have a `function` that **deletes** part of an object, calls another `function`, and then that other function calls the original after doing some more stuff.

I need the current state of that variable to be saved, so that when I **remove** a key when the `function` is called the first time, that key is still gone when called the second time.

As is, the `onclick` event calls `testFunction` while passing a mouse event.

How can I instead call the function while preserving the local variable, or at least one local variable?

This is a simplified version of the structure of my code to show what I mean:

```
var dict_obj = {'test1': 'test_1', 'test2': 'test_2'}

function testFunction(dict_obj) {
  if (dict_obj) {
    delete Object.keys(dict_obj)[0]
      someOtherFunction()
  } else {
    console.log('Function complete')
  }
}

function someOtherFunction() {
  button.onclick = testFunction
}
```

Is there someway to do this without declaring a global `variable` or continually passing the parameter through an arrow `function` with the `onclick`? In my actual code I have a lot of potential "paths" the function can go through, so passing it locally isn't ideal since the code would get convuluted.

Comment: If you have not done so yet, learn about [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: What is the point of calling someOtherFunction in testFunction? Where does someOtherFunction even get the button DOM?

Comment: Note that `delete Object.keys(dict_obj)[0]` doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Another note: adding an event handler while handling an event, is often a code smell.

Comment: Your example doesn't quiet make sense. You declare global `dict_obj`, but than in `testFunction` you use the same name as a parameter, which will be an event object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create local scope:

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");

{//start local scope
  let dict_obj = {'test1': 'test_1', 'test2': 'test_2'}

  function testFunction() {
    console.log(dict_obj);
    if (Object.keys(dict_obj).length) {
      delete dict_obj[Object.keys(dict_obj)[0]]
        someOtherFunction()
    } else {
      console.log('Function complete')
    }
  }

  function someOtherFunction() {
    button.onclick = testFunction;
  }

  someOtherFunction();
}//end of local scope

console.log(dict_obj);//error
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect and exactly what I was looking for.